# Accessing Value from constructor

Tags: c++

In my isEmpty function I want to check to see if the object is in the safe empty state and if so return true. The safe empty  occurs when denom = -1 which I declared in a constructor right above the function. How do I access this?
EDIT: apologies, I misread the line error. I miss used denom on a different line and I fixed the error. Sorry for wasting your time :(

```
 using namespace std;

namespace sict{

class Fraction{
private:
    int num;                // Numerator
    int denom;            // Denominator
    int gcd();            // returns the greatest common divisor of num and denom


  int max();        // returns the maximum of num and denom
  int min();        // returns the minimum of num and denom

public:
    void reduce();     // simplifies a Fraction number by dividing the 
                      // numerator and denominator to their greatest common divisor 
    Fraction();                             // default constructor
    Fraction(int n , int d=1);               // construct n/d as a Fraction number
    void display() const;    
    bool isEmpty() const;
 };
};
```

**Implementation*

```
#include "Fraction.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sict
{
  Fraction::Fraction()
  {  
        denom =-1;              // safe empty state

  }
 bool Fraction::isEmpty() const
 {

 //How do I access denom
 }
}
```

Comment: Same way you did in your constructor? Sorry, but I don't get the question.

Comment: How did you use it in the constructor?

Comment: isEmpty is a member function of the Fraction class and so all the member variables/functions are accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Just like this:

```
bool Fraction::isEmpty() const
{
    return denom == -1;
}
```